# What happens if you apply $\operatorname{QCoh}$ to $(X,\underline{\mathbb{C}}_X)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks

$\DeclareMathOperator\QCoh{QCoh}
\newcommand\numC{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand\numQ{\mathbb{Q}}$Let $X$ be a topological space (possibly a scheme). What happens if you apply $\QCoh$ to the prestack $(X,\underline{\numC}_{X})$, where $\underline{\numC}_{X}$ is the constant sheaf at $X$? What about $(X, \underline{\numQ}_{\ell})$?

Comment: You get locally constant sheaves of vector spaces.

Comment: @MarcHoyois I thought this, but I'm not sure this is true, since  you could have a locally constant sheaf on an affine variety which is not constant and thus not quasicoherent in this definition.

Comment: @WillSawin That was also the answer I was hoping for, or possibly something related (perhaps providing a different approach to constructible sheaves). Unfortunately, a map $\operatorname{Spec}(A) \to (X,\underline{\mathbb{C}}_{X})$ is just any continuous map (seemingly without restrictions) and a map of sheaves of rings $\underline{\mathbb{C}}_{\operatorname{Spec}(A)} \to \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}(A)}$. There can potentially be many such; if $A$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra, any pathological automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ provides you with one.

Comment: @WillSawin To clarify I was using the following definition, which I think is standard although rarely used: a sheaf of modules over a ringed space $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ is quasi-coherent if locally it is the cokernel of a map of free $\mathcal O_X$-modules (this is manifestly a local notion). For $\mathcal O_X=\underline{\mathbb C}_X$ we therefore get locally constant sheaves, at least if $X$ is locally connected or if we restrict to modules of finite presentation.

Comment: @MarcHoyois Sorry, I confused myself about what happens when you pull back a locally constant sheaf to an affine variety. But I don't think your definition makes sense for prestacks, so I see a map from the category of Zariski-locally constant sheaves to this category of quasicoherent sheaves but not yet vice versa.

Comment: To clarify, a quasicoherent sheaf on a prestack should produce a quasicoherent sheaf on each affine scheme mapping to it (i.e. an $A$-module for each $A$-point), in a way compatible with pullbacks between affine schemes. A locally constant sheaf on $X$ gives one of these, where, for each affine scheme $Z$ mapping to $(X, \underline{\mathbb C}_X)$, we pullback the locally constant sheaf and tensor with $\mathcal O_Z$, obtaining a sheaf which is locally $\mathcal O_Z \otimes V$ for a vector space $V$, hence locally quasicoherent, hence quasicoherent.

Comment: Exceptional automorphisms of $\mathbb C$ are no problem for this. But it's not immediately obvious to me that every quasicoherent sheaf (which does not necessarily arise from a literal sheaf on the underlying topological space) arises from this construction.